# how to compare two number to find number of corresponding different digits

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, numbers

I have two number `1100` and `1010` then I would like to find out the number of different corresponding digits among them, so the ans for above example would be `2` since 2nd digit and 3rd digit both numbers are different.

I am using this program

```
def req_fun(arr, b): # arr :['1100', '0011', '0101', '1110'], b:'1010'
    count = 0
    for i in arr:
        for j in range(len(b)):
            count += int(i[j])^int(b[j])
    return count
```

I needed the better way to achieve this since I am getting TLE(time limit exceeded) using this approach.

NOTE: all the numbers will be strictly be `0` and `1`

Comment: There are more efficient implementations of Hamming distance, but the TLE suggest to me that the problem is bigger than this: probably the problem you are solving requires a fundamentally different algorithm

Comment: Do you want to return total number of different digits or number of different digits per item in list `arr`?

Comment: @amangoyal total number of different digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't clear in the question that If you want to return total number of different digits or number of different digits per item in the list `arr`. So I am assuming that you want to return total number of different digits.

If you sum both the numbers(algebraic sum), then the sum of two corresponding digits is `1` if and only if the two digits are different and this fact can be used to count number of different digits as shown below

```
def count_different(arr, b):
    diff_digits = 0
    for i in arr:
        diff_digits += str(int(i)+int(b)).count('1')
    return diff_digits
```

in case you want to return number of different digits for each item in `arr` them append each count in the list and return a list.

```
def count_different(arr, b):
    diff_digits = 0
    l = []
    for i in arr:
        diff_digits += str(int(i)+int(b)).count('1')
        l.append(diff_digits)
    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure Python way of `sum` on a generator with `zip()`:

```
a, b = 1100, 1010

print(sum(x != y for x, y in zip(str(a), str(b))))
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [the Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of the two strings, that is the differences between two strings (equal in length).

Luckily, there is also a [Python code on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance#Algorithm_example), so you can just grab and use it.

The code is:

```
def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    """Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences"""
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(el1 != el2 for el1, el2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(a & 2**c != b & 2**c for c in range(4))
```

This `4` is your hardcoded len of binary representations. `a` and `b` are your numbers.

Edit: this `sum` acts as count of true values as True evaluates to 1 and False to 0.